# GNU Makefile - modifying Makefile after changing project directory structure, and outputing to different folders

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make

I am working on an old Makefile for a project. The current project consists of all of the files dumped into a single project named `src`.

I want to restructure the project to have the following structure:

```
-src           (C files)
  |- include   (header files)
- build        (intermediary build files - *.d, *.o)
- bin          (built binary [executable])
- lib          (built library)
```

Here is a summary of the Makefile, and the changes I have managed to do so far (created the new folder structures etc.).

```
SOURCE_DIR = src
HEADER_DIR = $(SOURCE_DIR)/include
BUILD_DIR = build
LIB_DIR = lib
BIN_DIR = bin


OBJS = foo.o foobar.o foofoobar.o barbar.o barfoo.o barbarfoo.o 

all: dir release

dir:
    test -d $(HEADER_DIR) || mkdir -p $(HEADER_DIR)
    test -d $(BUILD_DIR) || mkdir $(BUILD_DIR)
    test -d $(LIB_DIR) || mkdir $(LIB_DIR)
    test -d $(BIN_DIR) || mkdir $(BIN_DIR)


debug : CC = gcc
debug : CFLAGS = -std=c99 -O0 -g
debug : LDLIBS = -lm
debug : project

release : CC = gcc
release : CFLAGS = -std=c99 -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing
release : LDLIBS = -lm
release : project

debug_cpp : CC = g++
debug_cpp : CFLAGS = -x c++ -std=c++11 -O0 -g
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),Darwin) # macOS
debug_cpp : WARNINGS += -Wcast-qual
endif
debug_cpp : LDLIBS = -lstdc++
debug_cpp : project

release_cpp : CC = g++
release_cpp : CFLAGS = -x c++ -std=c++11 -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),Darwin) # macOS
release_cpp : WARNINGS += -Wcast-qual
endif
release_cpp : LDLIBS = -lstdc++
release_cpp : project

.c.o :
    $(CC) -c  $(CFLAGS) $(WARNINGS) $<

project : main.o libproject.a
    $(CC) -o $(BIN_DIR)/project main.o -L. -lproject $(LDLIBS)
    
libproject.a : $(OBJS)
    rm -f $@   
    ar cq $@ $(OBJS)   

clean : 
    -rm -f main.o $(OBJS)
    -rm -f $(BIN_DIR)/project $(BIN_DIR)/libproject.a
    
.PHONY : all project clean debug release debug_cpp release_cpp

# Dependencies generated using "gcc -MM *.c"

foo.o: file1.c afile.h bfile.h cfile.h dfile.h hfile.h \
  gfile.h file2.c file3.c fil4.c file5.c
```

How do I modify the Makefile to:

1. Build the binary executable and place in `bin` folder (whilst dumping intermediate files in $(BUILD) folder
2. Build the binary library and place in `lib` folder (whilst dumping intermediate files in $(BUILD) folder

Comment: This is not a very good structure. Your recipes will not work if something depends on `dir` but the user invokes `make target`. Instead you want each target to depend on the *specific* director(ies) it requires. Because directory date stamps will be updated when a directory is written to, probably use a separate dot file in each directory as the actual dependency (dike `lib/library.a: lib/.created $(otherdeps)`)

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I spotted that too myself. I will modify the Makefile locally - bearing that point in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I only fixed the `release` target, so you can do the rest.

The `.PRECIOUS` and %/.` rule is a good way to make directories automatically.

The `.SECONDEXPANSION` and `| $$(@D)/.` bits are a good way to depend on making the directories.

You generated dependencies and included them by hand (I did not include them in my answer).  Good.  You have to remember to update them as needed. The Make manual contains a recommendation on how to handle such dependencies fully automatically.  In my opinion, this automatic method does not always work correctly, so one has to do it manually.

Here you go

```
SOURCE_DIR = src
BUILD_DIR = build/
LIB_DIR = lib
BIN_DIR = bin
PROJECT := $(BIN_DIR)/project
LIB := $(LIB_DIR)/libproject.a

OBJS:= $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR),foo.o foobar.o foofoobar.o barbar.o barfoo.o barbarfoo.o)

all: release

release : CC = gcc
release : CFLAGS = -std=c99 -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing
release : LDLIBS = -lm
release : $(PROJECT)

.PRECIOUS: %/.
%/.:
    mkdir -p $(@:/.=)

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(BUILD_DIR)%.o : $(SOURCE_DIR)/%.c Makefile | $$(@D)/.
    $(CC) -c  $(CFLAGS) $(WARNINGS) $< -o $@

$(PROJECT) : $(BUILD_DIR)main.o $(LIB) Makefile | $$(@D)/.
    $(CC) -o $@ $< -L$(LIB_DIR) -lproject $(LDLIBS)
    
$(LIB) : $(OBJS) Makefile | $$(@D)/.
    rm -f $@   
    ar cq $@ $(OBJS)   
    
.PHONY : all clean release
```